# How to show different background images and logos in Azure ADB2C per customer (passed in Url)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a web application that uses Azure ADB2C to authenticate users. Therefore we currently use a custom landing page with a login button that redirects the user to Azure ADB2C login page. We use company branding for logo and background on login page.

The landing page is branded for each of our customers and can be reached through different Urls:
https://www.mypage.com/login/customer1 -> show background image and logo of customer 1
https://www.mypage.com/login/customer2 -> show background image and logo of customer 2

My question is if there is any way to directly open Azure ADB2C login page and display background image and logo of the customer passed in Url. In other words changing company branding at runtime or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C supports dynamic page customization based on query parameters that are sent to the login url.

You can see how to configure dynamic page customisation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-dynamic-custom-page-content-uri).

And in your application, you can pass custom query parameters in the login url, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#pass-a-custom-query-string-parameter) for .Net Core, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app-options#pass-a-custom-query-string-parameter) for SPA apps.